# How to use netcat to provide input to DPDK examples?

Tags: linux, network-programming, ip, netcat, dpdk

I'm running the DPDK Skeleton example from here:

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/sample_app_ug/skeleton.html

Getting this output:

```
sudo ./dpdk-skeleton -l 1 -n 4

EAL: Detected CPU lcores: 4
EAL: Detected NUMA nodes: 1
EAL: Detected static linkage of DPDK
EAL: Multi-process socket /var/run/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'PA'
EAL: VFIO support initialized
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_igb (8086:1533) device: 0000:05:00.0 (socket -1)
EAL: Probe PCI driver: net_e1000_igb (8086:1533) device: 0000:0a:00.0 (socket -1)
TELEMETRY: No legacy callbacks, legacy socket not created
Port 0 MAC: 98 b7 85 00 5b 87
Port 1 MAC: 6c b3 11 52 a3 29

Core 1 forwarding packets. [Ctrl+C to quit]
```

How do I generate input frames/packets, so the above example does "something"?

I tried netcat from the same host but it didn't seem to work:

```
nc localhost 2399
```

I wasn't sure which port (because the DPDK application doesn't log a port) so I assumed I could use any port.

How/can I use netcat on the same host to provide input to DPDK examples?

I have a second machine (and an Ethernet cable) if that's required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the port listened by `dpdk-skeleton`, run this first :

```
ps -ef | grep dpdk-skeleton
```

let's say you get PID 6666, then

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep "LISTEN.*6666/"
```

*Update*

You can try this single command :

```
sudo netstat -anp|grep -P "LISTEN\s+$(pgrep -f dpdk-skeleton)"
```

Comment: Hi (again), I may not have asked my question properly (or I have misunderstood). I thought the Skeleton app would receive frames/packets and therefore I need to send it frames/packets using `netcat`

Comment: Once you find the port number, then you can use netcat to send frames/packets, if I understand well.

Comment: Ah. If the first command gets the port, why do we need the second command?

Comment: The first command get only the process ID (PID)

Comment: I'll ask rest in a new question....